# Regex to replace string that has code in it

Tags: javascript, regex, string

This string

```
"START";var settings ={"dev":false,"production":"n","id":"bcdef","key":"1234xyz","secret":"22sdfas"}
; return { getSettings: function(setting) { if (settings[setting]) { return settings[setting]; } return null; } };"END"
```

how to replace it with regex to become this

```
"START";var __REPLACED = console.log('replaced');"END"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write this function for your purpose:

```
/**
 * This function assumes string as a argument and
 * replaces everything  between "START" and "END"
 * with "START";var __REPLACED = console.log('replaced');"END"
 * @param input string
 * @author Georgi Naumov
 * gonaumov@gmail.com for contacts and
 * suggestions.
 */
function replaceString(input) {
    var re = /^("START")(?:(?:(?!"END")[\s\S])+)("END")$/g;
    return input.replace(re, function (match, p1, p2) {
        return p1 + ";var __REPLACED = console.log('replaced');" + p2;
    });
}
```

Here can be seen unit tests, which check the function:

http://gonaumov.github.io/stringReplacer/

Comment: The traditional way to match everything including newlines in JavaScript is with `[\s\S]`.  `(?:.|\s)` is not a viable alternative, because `.` and `\s` can both match spaces and tabs, making it extremely inefficient.

Comment: awesome! exactly what I need!